# Help with verbs following 'hasn't'

Tags: past-participles

I know that the verb following has or have must be in past participle. But why did Google say that the following sentence is correct: "He hasn't texted me in 2 days."

Can someone explain to me why it's correct or incorrect?

> Ex 1: He hasn't run home. or He hasn't ran home.
>   Ex 2: He hasn't tell me anything. or he hasn't told me anything.
>   Ex 3: She hasn't come home in 2 days. or she hasn't came home in 2 days.

Why is it that the past particle of "tell" is "told" and the past participle of "come" is "come"? Shouldn't the past participle of "come" be "came"?

Comment: Well, ["texted" is a part participle](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/how-to-use-text-as-a-verb).

Comment: It is but that doesnt explain why the past particle of Come isnt came,

Comment: There is no real "explaining" to do. [The simple past is 'came'; the past participle is 'come'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/come). Sometimes verbs have "irregular" past participles. They don't have to follow a pattern.

Comment: I googled the past participle of Come and its not came. The past tense of Come is Came. But not the past participle.

Comment: @AlanCarmack does that mean that i have to go learn irregular verbs?

Comment: If there were any way of predicting irregular verbs, we wouldn't call them irregular.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Text* is a **regular verb**.  For all regular verbs, the past tense and past participle are the same.  You form both by adding *-ed* to the base (sometimes with consonant doubling in the spelling).

*Come*, *run*, and *tell* are **irregular verbs**, so you can't just add *-ed*.  For some irregular verbs, like *tell*, the past tense and past participle are the same, so you only have to memorize one form.  For others, like *come* and *run*, the two forms are different, and you have to memorize both separately.

```
  past tense    past participle
  -----------   ----------------
  texted        texted　　　　　　←　Regular, so both forms are the same
  told          told  　　　　　　←　Irregular, but both forms are the same
  ran           run   　　　　　　←　Irregular, and the two forms are different
  came          come  　　　　　　←　Irregular, and the two forms are different
```

To form a perfect construction, use the perfect auxiliary *have* followed by the past participle form of the verb:

> 1. He hasn't **run** home.
> 2. He hasn't **come** home in two days.
> 3. He hasn't **told** me anything.
> 4. He hasn't **texted** me in two days.

You'll just have to memorize the past participle form for irregular verbs.

Comment: Where can I find more?

Comment: In addition, there are some which are the same for all: set set set; cut cut cut; put put put; etc

Comment: @ESLIneedhelp, here is a useful list of irregular verbs. https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/605/

Comment: I wish I could up-vote three times, once for a great answer, a second time for finding a way to make the `<pre>` formatting useful on ELL, and a third time for getting those arrows in there without using an HTML escape code :)

Answer (score 3):

The simple past and the  past participle of *tell* is *told*.

Not all verbs work like this. Many verbs have three forms (*swim*, *swam*, *swum*). Some verbs have two forms for both the simple past and the past  participle (*dream*, *dreamed* or *dreamt*,  *dreamed* or *dreamt*). Some verbs have two participle forms:  (*light*, *lit*, *lit* or *lighted*). Note that over time, forms change and/or one form may be used more than the other (*lighted* used to be a widely used simple past form). There can be differences between dialects also, and between American English and British English, or between North American usage and British usage.

As far as *come*, *came*, *come*, I have no idea why the past participle is *come* and not *came*. But there are others like this: *run*, *ran*, *run*.

There may be historical reasons; what's important is to look a word up in [a good dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/come)  and just accept whatever it gives you for the past and past participle.